# Get the last chunk of upload file

Tags: php, chunked-encoding

So basically https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki as the uploader and I am using its chunk feature moving on in the server side. I am having a problem in getting the last chunk of the uploaded file.

What I am trying to do is save only to db once the chunks reaches the last the chunk or if the uploader finishes uploading the chunks

ex. chunk size = 10mb

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE']) )
    {


$content_range = preg_split('/[^0-9]+/', $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE']);

// if file is greater or equal to 10mb
if( $content_range[2] + 1 == $content_range[3] )
    {
        insert data to database here
    } 
    // if file does not need to be chunked file is less than chunk size
    else
    {
        also insert the data to database
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $is_chunked_upload = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE']);
    if ($is_chunked_upload) {
        $is_last_chunk = false;

        // [HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE] => bytes 10000000-17679248/17679249 - last chunk looks like this

        if (preg_match('|(\d+)/(\d+)|', $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE'], $range)) {

            if ($range[1] == $range[2] - 1) {
                $is_last_chunk = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```